# Garbage collection in JavaScript multiplayer game

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, memory-management, animation

I am currently creating a Multiplayer Game using node.js and web sockets. The client side is receiving the positional information and applying it to all the players on the client side. Each client stores a list of all game elements.

The main issue I am experiencing at the moment is a large amount of Garbage Collection. I am unsure what could be causing this, since I followed all of the tips I have found online; Set Variables to null to make sure they are collected asap. Dont create objects during runtime etc.

After running a profile, this is the result:

[image]

As you can see, when the GC kicks in, the game stops for a long time.

How can I reduce/remove GC and object creation from my code. It is fully working, but it performs poorly on low end devices.

I initialize all the arrays at the start.

```
var energies = [];
var walls = [];
var users = [];
var leaderboard = [];
```

Those arrays are then filled with data by the server:

```
socket.on('serverTellPlayerMove', function(userData, strEnergy) {
    var visible = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < userData.length;) {
        if ((userData[i] == 1) == true) {
            visible.push({
                p : userData[0 + i] == 1,
                score : userData[1 + i],
                x : userData[2 + i],
                y : userData[3 + i],
                angle : userData[4 + i],
                hue : userData[5 + i],
                name : userData[6 + i],
                dead : userData[7 + i] == 1,
                dying : userData[8 + i] == 1
            });
            i += 9;
        } else {
            visible.push({
                x : userData[0 + i],
                y : userData[1 + i],
                angle : userData[2 + i],
                hue : userData[3 + i],
                name : userData[4 + i],
                dead : userData[5 + i] == 1,
                dying : userData[6 * i] == 1
            });
            i += 7;
        }
    }

    // SET DATA:
    for (var i = 0; i < visible.length; i++) {
        if (visible[i].p) {
            var playerData = visible[i];
            i = visible.length;
        }
    }
    if (userData != "") {
        if (playerType == 'player') {
            // HOW MUCH YOU MOVED BY:
            var xoffset = player.x - playerData.x;
            var yoffset = player.y - playerData.y;
            player.x = playerData.x;
            player.y = playerData.y;
            player.angle = playerData.angle;
            player.hue = playerData.hue;
            player.xoffset = isNaN(xoffset) ? 0 : xoffset;
            player.yoffset = isNaN(yoffset) ? 0 : yoffset;
            player.dead = playerData.dead;
            document.getElementById("killsText").innerHTML = "Score: "
                    + playerData.score;
        }
    }

    // DEATH ANIM:
    for (var i = 0; i < visible.length; i++) {
        if (visible[i].dying) {
            createExplosion(visible[i].x, visible[i].y);
        }
    }

    // DEATH ANIM:
    for (var i = 0; i < visible.length; i++) {
        if (visible[i].dying) {
            createExplosion(visible[i].x, visible[i].y);
        }
    }

    users = visible;
    visible = null;
    var energiesList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < strEnergy.length; i += 5) {
        energiesList.push({
            x : strEnergy[0 + i],
            y : strEnergy[1 + i],
            index : strEnergy[2 + i],
            animate : strEnergy[3 + i] == 1,
            hue : strEnergy[4 + i]
        });
    }

    var energyT = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < energiesList.length; ++i) {
        energyT = energiesList[i];
        if (energyT.animate) {
            energyT.animScale = 0;
        } else {
            if (energies[energyT.index] != undefined)
                energyT.animScale = energies[energyT.index].animScale;
        }
        energies[energyT.index] = energyT;
    }
    energiesList = null;
    energyT = null;
    userData = null;
    strEnergy = null;
});
```

This code is called 30 times a second. This updates every users data on each client side. It also updates the pellet data. Pellets are objects that can be picked up by players in the game. The above snippet does most of the logical work on the client side.

Each object is also rendered as follows:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
        || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame
        || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function(callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();

function animloop() {
    gameLoop();
    animLoopHandle = window.requestAnimFrame(animloop);
}

function doGame() {
    now = Date.now();
    delta = now - lastUpdate;
    lastUpdate = now;

    startX = player.x - (screenWidth / 2);
    startY = player.y - (screenHeight / 2);

    graph.fillStyle = backgroundColor;
    graph.fillRect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    drawgrid();
    drawEnergies(energies);
    drawPlayers(users);
    drawWalls(walls);
}
```

And the actual rendering:

```
function drawPlayers(playersToDraw) {
    var playerC = null;
    var fontSize = Math.max(playerRadius / 1.2, 11);
    var radiusD = (playerRadius * 2.0);
    for (var z = 0; z < playersToDraw.length; z++) {
        playerC = playersToDraw[z];
        if (!playerC.dead) {
            var shapeX = playerC.x - startX;
            var shapeY = playerC.y - startY;
            var rotation = (Math.PI / 180) * playerC.angle;
            scale = radiusD;
            graph.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + playerC.hue + ', 50%, 45%)';
            graph.strokeStyle = 'hsl(' + playerC.hue + ', 50%, 60%)';
            graph.lineJoin = "round";
            graph.lineWidth = playerHRadius;
            graph.save();
            graph.translate(shapeX, shapeY);
            graph.rotate(rotation);
            graph.beginPath();
            graph.moveTo(0, (-2 * scale / 3));
            graph.lineTo((-scale / 2), scale / 3);
            graph.lineTo((scale / 2), scale / 3);
            graph.lineTo(0, (-2 * scale / 3));
            graph.closePath();
            graph.stroke();
            graph.fill();
            graph.restore();
        }
    }
    playerC = null;
}
```

As you can see I am setting playerC to null in an Attempt to make it be collected by the GC.

There are some more rendering functions as well, but they are all very similar to the player draw function.

How do I reduce GC on this code and does the data received from the server need to be collected as well?

---

I have attempted to implement v-sync, but then I realized that the movement data is sent by the server, to there is no way to use delta time or v-sync.

As suggested, I did a Heap Snapshot. Here is the result:

[image]

And here is what was actually removed:

[image]

After some further looking around, I found this:
[image]

It points at the data received from the server. Also I noticed some throw TypeError statements, what could be causing that?

Here is a LIVE DEMO of the code in action:
http://www.vertix.io

Comment: I suggest you [try taking snapshots of your heap](http://addyosmani.com/blog/taming-the-unicorn-easing-javascript-memory-profiling-in-devtools/). The timeline can only tell us about the GC event, but not so much about what it was claiming back. And we're not even sure if the offending code is even in the given snippets.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have added the Heap Snapshot to the question.

Comment: [Here's an answer that references the "three-snapshot technique"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19726918/575527). Shows you what built up memory usage when you used it (first to second snapshot), and what was claimed or not claimed (second to third snapshot)

Comment: Thanks again. Very helpful. I have discovered that drawPlayer is one of the culprits.

Comment: I cant figure out where this array could be coming from.

Comment: You create an array each time you enter the socket handler: `var visible = [];` that is what is getting collected.

Comment: [This article (High-Performance, Garbage-Collector-Friendly Code)](http://buildnewgames.com/garbage-collector-friendly-code/) will help you for the future of your games. Particularly the notion of Object Pooling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use a static approach for the visible array, avoiding the push instruction: declare and fill the array with dummy structures outside the socket.on handler and then iterate over the items to change their value.

Use a variable to keep the length of the received values, instead of calling visible.length().

You are also copying many times your data: in Javascript `var playerData = visible[i];` makes another copy of the data, consider accessing the player's data by index instead of copying it in another structure.

The same problem arises for the `energiesList` array. Define it outside the event and only update its values inside, keeping the real lenght in a variable.

Hope it helps.

---

EDIT

This is how the code should be refactored (you need to test it)

```
MAX_VISIBLES = 500;
VISIBLE_PLAYER = 1;
VISIBLE_OTHER = 0;
var visible = [];
for (var i = 0; i < MAX_VISIBLES; i++) {
    visible.push({
        type: 0,
        p : 0,
        score : 0,
        x : 0,
        y : 0,
        angle : 0,
        hue : 0,
        name : 0,
        dead : 0,
        dying : 0
    });
}

// Just need it once (only if you use it anywhere else in the code)
users = visible;
// You'll need it if you want to iterate over users
var usersLength = 0;

MAX_ENERGIES = 1000;
var energiesList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < MAX_ENERGIES; i++) {
    energiesList.push({
        x : 0,
        y : 0,
        index : 0,
        animate : 0,
        hue : 0
    });
}

socket.on('serverTellPlayerMove', function(userData, strEnergy) {
    for (var i = 0, visibleLength = 0; i < userData.length; visibleLength++) {
        if ((userData[i] == 1) == true) {
            visible[visibleLength].type = VISIBLE_PLAYER;
            visible[visibleLength].p : userData[0 + i] == 1;
            visible[visibleLength].score : userData[1 + i];
            visible[visibleLength].x : userData[2 + i];
            visible[visibleLength].y : userData[3 + i];
            visible[visibleLength].angle : userData[4 + i];
            visible[visibleLength].hue : userData[5 + i];
            visible[visibleLength].name : userData[6 + i];
            visible[visibleLength].dead : userData[7 + i] == 1;
            visible[visibleLength].dying : userData[8 + i] == 1;
            i += 9;

            var playerData = visible[visibleLength];
        } else {
            visible[visibleLength].type = VISIBLE_OTHER;
            visible[visibleLength].x : userData[2 + i];
            visible[visibleLength].y : userData[3 + i];
            visible[visibleLength].angle : userData[4 + i];
            visible[visibleLength].hue : userData[5 + i];
            visible[visibleLength].name : userData[6 + i];
            visible[visibleLength].dead : userData[7 + i] == 1;
            visible[visibleLength].dying : userData[8 + i] == 1;
            i += 7;
        }
    }
// I don't think you need this cycle: playerdata can be assigned
// during userData parsing
//    // SET DATA:
//    for (var i = 0; i < visible.length; i++) {
//        if (visible[i].p) {
//            var playerData = visible[i];
//            i = visible.length;
//        }
//    }
    if (userData != "") {
        if (playerType == 'player') {
            // HOW MUCH YOU MOVED BY:
            var xoffset = player.x - playerData.x;
            var yoffset = player.y - playerData.y;
            player.x = playerData.x;
            player.y = playerData.y;
            player.angle = playerData.angle;
            player.hue = playerData.hue;
            player.xoffset = isNaN(xoffset) ? 0 : xoffset;
            player.yoffset = isNaN(yoffset) ? 0 : yoffset;
            player.dead = playerData.dead;
            document.getElementById("killsText").innerHTML = "Score: "
                    + playerData.score;
        }
    }

    // DEATH ANIM:
    for (var i = 0; i < visibleLength; i++) {
        if (visible[i].dying) {
            createExplosion(visible[i].x, visible[i].y);
        }
    }

    // DEATH ANIM:
    for (var i = 0; i < visibleLength; i++) {
        if (visible[i].dying) {
            createExplosion(visible[i].x, visible[i].y);
        }
    }

// See above
//    users = visible;
//    visible = null;
    usersLength = visibleLength;

    for (var i = 0, energiesListLength = 0; i < strEnergy.length; i += 5, energiesListLength++) {
        energiesList[energiesListLength].x : strEnergy[0 + i];
        energiesList[energiesListLength].y : strEnergy[1 + i],
        energiesList[energiesListLength].index : strEnergy[2 + i];
        energiesList[energiesListLength].animate : strEnergy[3 + i] == 1;
        energiesList[energiesListLength].hue : strEnergy[4 + i];
    }

    var energyT = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < energiesListLength; ++i) {
        energyT = energiesList[i];
        if (energyT.animate) {
            energyT.animScale = 0;
        } else {
            if (energies[energyT.index] != undefined)
                energyT.animScale = energies[energyT.index].animScale;
        }
        energies[energyT.index] = energyT;
    }

// You don't need to force GC: you need to avoid GC
//    energyT = null;
//    userData = null;
//    strEnergy = null;
});
```

Comment: "makes another copy of the data" - false. Objects are always copied by reference in JavaScript. This is why `clone()` and `deepClone()` functions exist. The performance difference in copying this reference would be *incredibly* superfluous.

Comment: Ok, I must agree with you @dan. Still the line `var visible = [];` has to be removed from inside the socket handler.

Comment: @N74: Setting variables to `null` does not trigger garbage collection. It can make it _easier_ to garbage-collect those objects. Even the `delete` keyword does not trigger the garbage collector. This happens at the browser's discretion. The best you can do is limit the amount of new objects that get created, which can be difficult if you are receiving JSON over the network and then parsing it into objects.

Comment: @GregBurghardt thanks for the clarification. In the comment I just wanted to warn the OP that setting these variables to `null` is almost of no use in his code.

Comment: Very true. Unless a function closure is involved, null-ing object references doesn't do much but bulk up your code.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from your last comment 'drawPlayer is one of the culprits', you use `graph` for drawing operations. The `graph` context is a huge bitmap to manipulate since it is as big as the screen:

`graph.fillRect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);`

To rotate  and translate such a big bitmap costs a lot of memory and processing power.

In such cases I recommend using the following technique:

Create an 'offscreen' canvas with the same width and height of the player image and draw your player on that context. If you want to rotate within your offscreen canvas, make sure the rotated image fits in the offscreen canvas.

After that, you draw the content of your offscreen canvas onto your main stage.

You can write the contents of a canvas on another canvas [with the drawImage function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage):

In [this article the technique called pre-rendering is explained further](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/#toc-pre-render) with a mario character resembling your 'player'.

Other remarks about your drawplayer routine:

Use length caching with for loops : store the length in a variable:

```
for (var z = 0; z < playersToDraw.length; z++) {

var len = playersToDraw.length;
for (var z = 0; z < len; z++) {
```

or:

```
for(var z=0, len=playersToDraw.length; z < len; z++){
```

Another thing, just as N74 mentioned, don't copy the variable if it is not really nescessary.

Don't use this:

```
playerC = playersToDraw[z];
playerC.blabla
```

Just use:

```
playersToDraw[z].blabla
```

And another thing, move the line:

```
scale = radiusD;
```

Out of the for-loop, now it runs every iteration and that isn't nescessary. Or instead of:

```
var radiusD = (playerRadius * 2.0);
```

use this at once and be done with it:

```
var scale = (playerRadius * 2.0);
```

Comment: @ your point about copying the variable; objects are copied by reference. The difference between `array[index].value` and `const host = array[index]; host.value` are for legibility's sake only.

Comment: I say that in a short function like this, where performance is of the most importance, code should be concise as possible and prevail over readability. I understand that player.blabla reads nicer than playersToDraw[z].blabla, but there is just no need to make a copy of that variable (that references to the same value indeed)

Comment: If you like, you can suggest how I should rephrase my words and I will gladly update it. :)

Comment: Well, one of the principles of [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) is that a function may only ever access `a.b` or `a.c`, but never `a.b.c`. Ideally, the loop should be in a separate function for testing purposes which passes the function `a.b`, and then that function accesses `b.c`. Further, OP is reusing the variable `array[index]`. In my opinion, it makes more sense to assign that to a temporary variable to avoid extra lookups (even if they are O(1)) and to DRY up the code.

Comment: in short: `player.dead` `player.x` and `player.y` is significantly more legible than `array[index].dead`, `array[index].x` and `array[index].y`

Comment: s/loop/loop iteration

Comment: It's a matter of taste I am affraid. Don't get me wrong, I am all 100% for readability! But with high performance canvas drawing applications I stick to this approach (after doing it the way you're suggesting for a while).

Answer (score 1):

1. Create arrays with required size to prevent reallocation overhead

```
var visible = new Array(required_size);
```

You can look at [good overview for array allocations](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/109623/long-arithmetic-addition-in-js/109634#answer-109634) from codereview, but different topic.

2. GC cleans temporary objects and time it need to clean them depends on their number, so you can use [closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/?hl=en) to inline everything that can be inlined to decrease number of objects GC had to process.
3. Not GC optimization, but related to performance: do not search DOM element frequently, save link to them and reuse variable.

```
var killsLabel = document.getElementById("killsText");
// when you need it
killsLabel.innerHTML = "Score: " + playerData.score;
```